# Are there any known results on inverse invariant theory?

Tags: reference-request, invariant-theory

I understand the basics of invariant theory in commutative algebra.  Assume we are working over a polynomial ring in n variables over a field of characteristic 0.  What I’m looking for are examples or results of an inverse process.  I was thinking along the lines of given a homogeneous polynomial f find the largest (maximal?) subgroup G of $\mathrm{SL}(n, k)$ for which f is invariant under the action of G on the polynomial ring.  Some examples of types of questions I have are:

If such a G could be found given f then would $k[x_{1}, ..., x_{n}]^{G}$ be the smallest subring of $k[x_{1}, ..., x_{n}]$ containing f that is an invariant subring for some subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(n, k)$?

EDIT:  Here’s an example of what I’m thinking.

Consider $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and let $f$ and $h$ be homogeneous polynomials.  Let $G_{f}$ be the largest subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ that leaves $f$ invariant and let $G_h$ be similarly defined.  Let S be a subring of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ that contains $f$ and $g$ that is a ring of invariants for some subgroup $G$ of $\mathrm{SL}(n, k)$.  I want to conclude that $$\mathbb{C}[x,y]^{G_{f}\cap G_{h}} \subset S $$
Would this be the same thing as saying that $G_{f}\cap G_{h}$ contains $G$ as a subgroup?

I’m working with $\mathrm{SL}(n,k)$ because I want to say there is a unique largest subgroup with for with a given homogeneous polynomial is invariant.  For instance the polynomial $x^2+y^2$ is invariant under the Klein 4 subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ and under the cyclic group of order 4.  It seems to me that restricting to $\mathrm{SL}(2,k)$ may allow one to say there is a largest subgroup but I don’t know this to be true.